# Unit Testing Download CSV in Spring

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, csv, spring-boot

I am writing a unit test for an endpoint in Spring which sends a csv file as the response. I am able to do checks like checking Status of the respone and the content type, but how can I compare the contents of the CSV? I tried to convert the response to string and do the comparison but without any success. Can any one point me in the right direction?

Here is what I tried:

```
public void testDownloadCSV() throws Exception {
    RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get
            (getRequestMapping("/downloadCSV/" + ID))
            .contentType(contentType);
    ResultActions result = getMockMvc().perform(request);
    String csvString = "CSV Data goes here";
    String resultString=content().toString();
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        result.andDo(print());
        Assert.assertTrue(csvString.equals(resultString));
    }
    // tests:
    result.andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType
            (contentType));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what kind of differences are you seeing when your are comparing String contents. Common problem is lack/presence of whitespace characters.

If that's your case, Just use Java library called [`Hamcrest`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) to compare your strings this way:

```
assertThat(actualContent, equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace(expectedContent));
```

If your logic is not order sensitive, I am afraid you'll need parse the CSV strings first into Lists, sort them and compare them afterwards.